# Would Indonesia have become a communist country if Soekarno hadn't stepped down?

Tags: cold-war, communism, indonesia

Along with Josip Tito and some other leaders, Soekarno is one of the founders of Non-Aligned Movement in 1961, which [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Non-Aligned-Movement) describes as an "abstention from the use of arrangements of collective defense to serve the particular interests of any of the big powers.".

Internally, he declared Nasakom, an abbreviation for Nationalism, Religion, and Communism. He made it clear that he stands in the neutral ground by supporting all three main political factions equally.

After the assassination of Kennedy, it seems that Soekarno's political attitude totally changed in favor of Soviet Bloc. One notable move was a purchase of Sverdlov-class cruiser from Soviet Union, which surely a political move, considering the Indonesian economy at that time, and the fact that the Sverdlov-class is an advanced cruiser. But even more bizare, Indonesia and some other communist countries even concluded a pact called Jakarta - Pnom Penh - Hanoi -  Peking - Pyongyang Axis.

Had [1965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/30_September_Movement) never happened, or Soekarno resisted to step down, would Indonesia become a communist country?

Comment: This appears to be a question about a hypothetical. History can only discuss what actually happened; history has no methods to discuss what _might have_ happened.  Having said that, I wonder if there is a way to revise the question to avoid the hypothetical and still get the answer that @imeluntuk wants.  Perhaps discuss the strength & alignment of domestic factions within Indonesia aligned with the various cold war factions?

Comment: Note that the usual English (or at least American) spelling is Sukarno.  so you might get better answers & search results if you use that.

Comment: I recommend rephrasing this along the lines MarkC.Wallace suggested as this looks to be a very interesting question!